# how to limit the Total Number of Form submissions per day

Tags: mysql, html, expressionengine

Can anyone guide me as to how to set a form to be enabled for a certain time period in a day.

Or how to limit the Total Number of Form submissions per day or per week etc.

For e.g.

I need the form to automatically be disabled as soon as 100 form submissions have been sent in a day or an hour etc.

100 submissions should be added to a table per day. The form should not accept any more submissions for the rest of the day, as soon as 100 entries have been sent.

Requirement: We need to handle a certain number of questions/submissions per day. The form should be disabled once the number of submissions in a certain table reaches 100 or any other number.

Which MySQL Query can I use ?

Or can the form be disabled by Javascript ?

Here is a simple form:

```
<p><label for="name">Name</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="name" value="name" id="name" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="email">Email Address</label><br />
   <input type="text" name="email" value="email" id="email" size="37" /></p>

<p><label for="comment">Comment</label><br />
   <textarea name="comment" rows="8" cols="35" id="comment">comment</textarea></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
```

---

Update: Thanks to Quentin

here is the code i have reached.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM data where channel_id='2'"; 

if (count <= 100) {show the form} else {show a message that the form is closed}
```

The table has 3 fields , 
[year] 
[month] 
and [day].
how do I use the CURDATE () in this manner as the date is divided into 3 fields ?

Comment: Limit...by what?  IP address?  Cookie?  Favorite color?

Comment: If it's a global limit, simply keep a count of it in a file

Comment: @AJ "Total Number" (mentioned in the question)

Comment: Couldn't he do something like - a mysql statement that had a WHERE that checked if SUM(submissions WHERE date...) < 100  ... I don't have the time to test it out atm, but - I'm sure someone here could just write it off the top of their head :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this client side.

A query along the lines of:

```
select count(*) from myTable where myDateColumn >= CURDATE();
```

should do the trick.

Use it when deciding if you should generate the form, and when deciding if you should accept the form submission.

Comment: How to hide the HTML form automatically when the number of submissions has reached ?

Comment: if (your result is => 100) { show a sorry message } else { show a form }

Comment: @Quentin Here is the code i have: `SELECT count(*) AS count FROM data where channel_id='2'"; if (count <= 100) {show the form} else {show a message that the form is closed} `

   The code is working fine

The table has 3 field , [year] [month] and [day], how do I use the CURDATE () in this manner as the date is divided into 3 fields ?

Comment: @Quentin, i used the following mysql code `select count(*) AS count from `exp_channel_titles` where `channel_id`="2" and `day`=CURDATE();` it does not work.  Yes, [day] is a field in the table, maybe day is conflicting with day function of mysql ?

Comment: Is it a date field? Define "does not work", what result do you get?

Comment: @Quentin, I got the mysql code to display what i needed I have posted the code as an Answer.

But how would i test it live in the cms, for e.g. the sql statement works fine in phpmyadmin query and it gives the correct result.

When does mysql change the date ? Does it do at 12 Midnight ?

Comment: Yes. The current date is the current date. When the date changes, so does the curdate().

Comment: @Quentin, So its supposed to work. I have around 8 mins left till midnight.

ill test to see with lowering the entries to 20, and enter test entries to see if the form will autohide or not. Ill update here.

Comment: @Quentin, one think i did different from your code. 

` myDateColumn >= CURDATE();`

I got 0 results with >= but when i changed it to <= , i got the correct result.

Comment: @Quentin, it worked perfectly. I lowered the entries till 20 per day. Ill test it again tomorrow.

Thanks @Quentin.

Comment: @Quentin, checked after 12 Midnight, the form did not appear automatically. It appears that teh <= is taking the previous day as well.


I tried using `SELECT count(*) AS count FROM exp_channel_titles where `channel_id`='2' and `day` **=** CURDATE()"`

with the  **=** operator, but it gives 0 records, even though there are records.

im stuck, what to do ?

Comment: Is `day` a date field? What values does it have?

Comment: day is a field for the day for e.g. day = 26 , month is a field for the month for e.g. (month = May) and Year is a field for year for e.g. (year=2011) , there is also entry_date field, here is a value from entry_date= 1306356678

Comment: the value of day is 26, its todays date, only the day part

Comment: Is 1306356678 a Unix style date?, its for the entry_date field

Comment: That would be the problem then. It appears to be an integer and not a date. CURDATE() returns a date (using the standard MySQL formatting: 2010-05-25).

Comment: Use `DAY(CURDATE())` instead to get the day of the month as an integer. Expect it to break as soon as you get more than a month of data though! You'll either have to deal with multiple columns, reorganise the table to make use of a date datatype, or flush old data at that point.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks ill try that. What about 1306356678 ? is it a UNix style date, since the field clearly says " entry_date"  and uses the date formatting of {date format="%F %d %Y"} stlye to get the date in readable form.

Comment: You can get the current unix time via http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp, I think. But you'd have to complicate things by working out when today started and getting the time for then.

Comment: @Quentin, your suggestion of using `DAY(CURDATE())` worked. Here is the final sql statement ----- `SELECT count(*) AS count FROM exp_channel_titles where `channel_id`='2' and `day` = DAY(CURDATE())`

Thanks alot.

Comment: @Quentin, i searched all over Google, but i could not find a solution. Yet you gave a pretty simple one. I tried searching for `DAY(CURDATE())` the solution you gave at google, i could not see even a single result on DAY(CURDATE()). How did you know ?

Comment: @Quentin, by the way, the `day` field in the table has its Datatype as `Char`

Comment: I was looking at the table of date related things in MySQL. `Char` is a rather odd choice of field for something that will hold a number.

Comment: @Quentin, im using ExpressionEngine CMS. Thats how they have set it up.

Answer (score 0):

On your page displaying the form:
Query your database: Use a MySQL COUNT on an index to get num rows (1row = 1 response??) where submitday = today

see the folloing links, esp the second, on extracting time/date
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

if numrows = 100
use javascript to 'display:none' your form, 'display:block' your div

have `<div  id="toomuch" style="display:none;"><p>I'm sorry this form is closed for the day, try again tomorrow</p></div>`

Comment: This won't stop automated submissions

Answer (score 0):

Add a time field to your database and instanciate with curdate then do this query

```
 SELECT count(id) from TABLE where DATA=CURDATE();
```

Then you can implements a function to in your code to handle the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count FROM `channel`

where `day` = DAY(CURDATE())

and `channel_id` = '2'
```

Now it needs to be tested in realtime, if it works with the CMS or not. Does the form hides or not.

The form does hide if i manually try to edit "  {if count <= '100'} " , the form does hide, but i am concerned if it will work automatically. I think ill have to wait till morning.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this right this is a form displayed on your website (not the control panel publish form?) - if so this fairly straightforward. Do a record count check on your DB (if that's where you're storing your form data) based on a timestamp as others have shown with the example SQL statement. When you're reached your limit you can display the form with no post value and disable it using javascript & style it so it looks un-usable (or don't display it all).

In pseudocode:

```
Set timeframe  = week, day, etc.
Set maxsubmissions = 100 (or whatever)

Set sumbissioncount = Query db to get number of submissions within timeframe 

If submissioncount is less than maxsubmissions
 {embed form}
Else 
 {embed disabled form}
End if
```

Note sql examples given will only count per day, not week, you'd have to modify that for a week for example - to make it generic use the between clause or plunk vars between the ranges in examples above: see related thread: [Date Range Query MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007929/date-range-query-mysql)

Comment: i was able to get what i needed by the code i have pasted above. 

Nevertheless, Thanks for your help