# How to get rows which have a date that's either today or was yesterday or the day before in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

My MySQL database table has dates stored in the MySQL format (YYYY-MM-DD). I need to construct an SQL query that will return rows with dates that either occur today or yesterday or a day before. For example, if the stored date is 1979-08-22, I would like this row returned if today is 8/22 (the same date in a different year) or 8/23 or 8/24.

I'm thinking of using the DAYOFYEAR() function, which returns a single value between 1 and 365 depending on the date. Here is the current query:

```
SELECT * FROM `theTable` WHERE DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-DAYOFYEAR(`theDate`) IN(0, 1, 2, -364, -363)
```

This query finds the difference in days between the current date and the stored date and if it's 3 days, it should return the result. It seems to work.

Is this the right way to achieve the result I want or is there another, more efficient way? Is this likely to cause issues with leap years?

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007929/date-range-query-mysql

Comment: @jeremyasnyder that question is close, but not the same. My query above works, but I'm verifying it here and wondering if there's anything I'm doing wrong or inefficiently.

Comment: You don't like (or care for) -365?

Comment: @bart In my test runs, the value of -365 never showed up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `datesTable`
    WHERE (
        MONTH(`theDate`) = MONTH(CURDATE())
        AND DAY(`theDate`) = DAY(CURDATE())
    ) OR (
        MONTH(`theDate`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
        AND DAY(`theDate`) = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
    ) OR (
        MONTH(`theDate`) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
        AND DAY(`theDate`) = DAY(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY))
    )
```

Done!

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,
if(right(date_field,5)<=right(curdate(),5),concat(year(curdate()),'-',right(date_field,5)),concat(year(curdate() - interval 1 year),'-',right(date_field,5))) as myfield
from table
having myfield between curdate() - interval 2 day and curdate()
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is more efficient? I'm asking because my query is 88 characters long and yours is 143.

Comment: Wrapped the dayofyear subtration with ABS .. NOW mine is smaller and still works! :-D #TWIS

Comment: Let's suppose today is 1st january. Your query will not find record of 30 and 31 of december while mine does. Query efficient is not based on chars length.

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to fix my query without using string methods - it just doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: How about now? `SELECT * FROM \`theTable\` WHERE DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-DAYOFYEAR(\`theDate\`) IN(0, 1, 2, -364, -363)`

Comment: Awesome! I'm gonna leave the question open to see if anyone can do better. Thanks!

Comment: Your query would have a bug with leap year. select dayofyear('2011-01-01') - dayofyear('2008-12-31') // -365 I think you have to add it in your IN clause.

Answer (score 1):

If you use mysql function on where clause, the optimizer can't use the index on that field (if there is an index on it)

You can check how the optimizer is going to treat your query with the EXPLAIN command

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `theTable` WHERE DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())-DAYOFYEAR(`theDate`) IN(0, 1, 2, -364, -363)
```

If the table is small and will not grow and your not concerned about performance you should not worry.

Me I would add a new VARCHAR field beside the DATETIME field and I would store the same information in this field but in a different order

```
DATETIME: 2011-01-01
VARCHAR: 01-01-2011
```

And I would create an index on the varchar field, this way you could run fast and easy extraction query like

```
SELECT * FROM `theTable` WHERE `varchar_date` LIKE '01-01-%'
```

Comment: There isn't an index on that field, but you're right - I should put one because I'm expecting a fair bit of growth in this table. Another option I was thinking was to split the table based on the months, so all the August dates go into one and Septembers go into another and only those tables get checked per month.

Answer (score 1):

Does it specifically have to be today, yesterday, or the day before - or the last 72 hours is also okay?

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field) BETWEEB CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 259200 AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

**update** It seems like I completly missed the part about the years being different... another possible solution (which works on days diff and not hours) which I added as a comment is `WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '1990-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(field, '1990-%m-%d')) <= 2`

Comment: It's more date-based than "within 72 hours", so this won't work. But this is an interesting way to do it too!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread the question and completely ignored the part about the years being different. A possible solution for that part is simply using `DATE_FORMAT(field, '1990-%m-%d')`, where 1990 is just some arbitrary year to normalize all the dates to. What about doing `WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '1990-%m-%d'), DATE_FORMAT(field, '1990-%m-%d')) <= 2`?

Comment: Oh, wait, that wouldn't work with the first two days of the year. Its possible to test for one of two conditions, the original one OR one with the field being formatted on 1989 instead of 1990, but its getting quite ugly

Answer (score 1):

This seems harder than it needs to be. What's wrong with something like:

```
WHERE thedate >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

If future dates are possible you will require an additional clause: `AND thedate <= CURRENT_DATE()`

Treating dates like strings and trying to do math is wrought of peril. Leap years, leap seconds, edge cases over year ends, etc. all cause problems. If there's a built in library capable of solving your problem you're much better off using it, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest, but it needs to disregard the year. CURDATE() could be 2001-08-23 while theDate is 1979-08-22.

Comment: ahh, sorry I missed that in your problem definition.

Comment: How about `WHERE theDate >= DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '1990-%m-%d', INTERVAL 2 DAY))`? (using @shesek's date 'normalisation' trick in the previous answer)