# SELECT some rows between 2 datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database like this:

```
ID->INT
Date->DateTime
```

Now i want to write a SELECT to fetch all rows where Date column between "2008/1/1" and "2010/1/1".

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007929/date-range-query-mysql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '2008-01-01' and '2010-01-01';
```

Answer (score 2):

You just apply a filter in a `WHERE` clause

```
select *
from yourtable
where date >= '2008-01-01' 
   and date <= '2010-01-01'
```